# jquery calling my helloworld web service

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf, web-services

I'm really new at this jquery stuff. I have a wcf web service running :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="GET", 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string SayHello();
}

public class HelloWorlService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello ";
    }
}
```

When I enter http://localhost:62604/HelloWorld.svc/SayHello into google chrome i get the following result : 
{"SayHelloResult":"Hello "}

So it appears to be working.

Now I create a default.html that looks like this:

```
<html>                                                                  
 <head>                                                                  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">


     function CallService() {
         $.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost:62604/HelloWorld.svc/SayHello",
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "json",
             processdata = false,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             sucess:function(data) { alert('success'); },
             error: function (e) { alert('failed'); }
         });
     }

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("a").click(function () {
             CallService();
         });
     });

 </script>                                                               
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  
   <a href="">Link</a>                                       
 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

So really simple stuff ... but it's not working ... i always get alert failed message ....
I'm a bit lost here, not sure what is wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: the default.html page is not hosted on a webserver, its just a simple file that I open on a browser. Could that be the reason why it's not working correctly?

Comment: it will be usefull if you post the error message

Comment: Does opening `http://localhost:62604/default.html` work?  If so, it's a security and you'll need to switch to JSONP to get this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your jQuery is, as far as I can tell, really simple to fix. Your "URL" parameter, is an absolute URL. Browser security settings restrict the use of URLs like this. Try using a relative URL to grab the data.

If you *have* to use an absolute URL, then have your server fetch the data from the external URL, then give it to jQuery in such a ways that only a relative URL is required.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ohh .. the default.html is not really hosted on any web server .. i just created a file and put some html code and opened it in the browser ... So is it because I'm not hosting it ...?

Comment: Well, depending on what webserver you are using, and how it is configured, `index.html` is looked for whenever you only call the filepath, without file name. Try renaming the file to `index.html` or just call it in your URL request.

Comment: I don't have a web server. It's just a file that i have on my desktop that I open with the browser ....

Comment: The file you are requesting in your sample code above is showing that it is called from a server located on your computer. Soo... your actually requesting the file from your desktop?

Comment: Ok. I think I had a misunderstanding when reading your prior comments. Sorry about that. :) I am thinking one of three problems is causing this: 1) Your address may not be correct 2) You are using an absolute URL, which is still prevented for security, so trying using a relative URL 3) the fact that this is not on a web-server may also be the cause. Try using a relative URL first, and if that doesn't work, upload your jQuery, HTML, and necessary files to a web-server, and use relative URLs there. As you can tell, it's all about relative URLs. ;D

Comment: yeah i think the whole issue is caused because its not hosted on a webserver. So I'll try to host everything on a webserver, the website and the webservice. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try to log the error:

```
error: function (e) { alert('failed:'+e); }
```

to see what is going on! and post it back here